# Error with Str::slug upgrading laravel 6 app into 8

Tags: laravel

I try to upgrade my laravel 6 app into 8 and got error :

```
   TypeError 

  call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class "Str" not found

  at app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php:30
     26▕         $slugger = config('tags.slugger');
     27▕ 
     28▕         $slugger = $slugger ?: '\Str::slug';
     29▕ 
  ➜  30▕         return call_user_func($slugger, $this->getTranslation('name', $locale));
     31▕     }
     32▕ }
     33▕ 

  1   app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php:30
      call_user_func()

  2   app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php:18
      App\Tag::generateSlug()
```

In file Http/Traits/HasSlug.php :

```
<?php

//namespace Spatie\Tags;
namespace App\Http\Traits;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


trait HasSlug
{
    public static function bootHasSlug()
    {
        static::saving(function (Model $model) {
            collect($model->getTranslatedLocales('name'))
                ->each(function (string $locale) use ($model) {
                    with(new self)->info( $locale,'bootHasSlug $locale::' );
                    $model->setTranslation('slug', $locale, $model->generateSlug($locale));
                });
        });
    }

    protected function generateSlug(string $locale): string
    {
        $slugger = config('tags.slugger');

        $slugger = $slugger ?: '\Str::slug';

        return call_user_func($slugger, $this->getTranslation('name', $locale));
    }
}
```

I know this issue with Str::slug when upgrading laravel, but I am not sure in which way can it be fixed here ?

**UPDATED PART :**
No that does not work.

If I remake :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait HasSlug
{
    public static function bootHasSlug()
    {
        static::saving(function (Model $model) {
            collect($model->getTranslatedLocales('name'))
                ->each(function (string $locale) use ($model) {
                    with(new self)->info( $locale,'bootHasSlug $locale::' );
                    $model->setTranslation('slug', $locale, $model->generateSlug($locale));
                });
        });
    }

    protected function generateSlug(string $locale): string
    {
        with(new self)->info( $locale, 'generateSlug  $locale::' );
        $slugger = config('tags.slugger');
        $slugger = $slugger ?: \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug;
//        $slugger = $slugger ?: \Illuminate\Support\Str::class.'::slug';
//        $slugger = $slugger ?: 'Str::slug';

        return call_user_func($slugger, $this->getTranslation('name', $locale));
    }
```

Running migrations I got error:

```
   TypeError 

  call_user_func(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, class "Str" not found

  at app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php:33
     29▕         $slugger = $slugger ?: \Illuminate\Support\Str::slug;
     30▕ //        $slugger = $slugger ?: \Illuminate\Support\Str::class.'::slug';
     31▕ //        $slugger = $slugger ?: 'Str::slug';
     32▕ 
  ➜  33▕         return call_user_func($slugger, $this->getTranslation('name', $locale));
     34▕     }
     35▕ }
     36▕ 

  1   app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php:33
      call_user_func()

  2   app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php:18
      App\Tag::generateSlug()
```

But in blade templates I can use

```
\Illuminate\Support\Str::plural(


$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 8.83.0
```

**UPDATED PART 2:**
I opened file https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags/blob/main/src/HasSlug.php
and copied content of it  into my app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php :

```
<?php

// namespace Spatie\HasSlug; // As namespace seemed invalid for me I tried in this way, but failed anyway
namespace Spatie\Tags;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait HasSlug
{
    public static function bootHasSlug()
    {
        static::saving(function (Model $model) {
            collect($model->getTranslatedLocales('name'))
                ->each(fn (string $locale) => $model->setTranslation(
                    'slug',
                    $locale,
                    $model->generateSlug($locale)
                ));
        });
    }

    protected function generateSlug(string $locale): string
    {
        $slugger = config('tags.slugger');

        $slugger ??= '\Illuminate\Support\Str::slug';

        return call_user_func($slugger, $this->getTranslation('name', $locale));
    }
}
```

In composer.json I updated line to the latest version:

```
"spatie/laravel-tags": "^4.3.0",
```

and run

```
composer update
```

with success.

I supposed that this  version is relative to laravel 8
But running migrations I got next error :

```
   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Trait "App\Http\Traits\HasSlug" not found

  at app/Tag.php:19
     15▕ 
     16▕ 
     17▕ 
     18▕ 
  ➜  19▕ class Tag extends Model implements Sortable
     20▕ {
     21▕     use funcsTrait;
     22▕ 
     23▕     use SortableTrait, HasTranslations, HasSlug;
```

I am not sure why I have app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php updare my app/, but looks like I need it there...

Thanks!

Comment: What if you replace `'\Str::slug';` with `Str::class.'::slug'` or `'\Illuminate\Support\Str::slug'`?

Comment: Please look UPDATED PART

Comment: Please look UPDATED PART 2

Comment: I uploaded project at https://github.com/sergeynilov/Votes8 Could you, pleasae, take a look and run migration ?

Comment: You've commited things to the storage folder. Since it's not linked by default, it can't be cloned. The storage folder should not be commited. I had to manually restore each folder for it to work.

Comment: I've fixed it. I'm posting my solution in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `call_user_func`, I used `app()` to instantiate the slugger defined in `config/tags.php`.

---

`config/tags.php`

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    'slugger' => [
        // the slugger class. Will be instantiated with whatever is passed in the args.
        // In this case: new Str(...[])  <- no args. Same as new Str() or new Str
        'class' => [
            'name' => Str::class,
            'args' => [],
        ],
        // the slugger method. If any extra args are needed, they will be used.
        // In this case: $slugger->slug($string, ...[]) <- no args, same as $slugger->slug($string)
        'method' => [
            'name' => 'slug',
            'args' => [],
        ],
    ],
];
```

---

`app/Http/Traits/HasSlug.php`

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait HasSlug
{
    protected function generateSlug(string $locale): string
    {
        // use Str's slug method by default.
        list($class, $class_args, $method, $method_args) = [
            config('tags.slugger.class.name', 'Illuminate\Support\Str'),
            config('tags.slugger.class.args', []),
            config('tags.slugger.method.name', 'slug'),
            config('tags.slugger.method.args', []),
        ];

        $string = $this->getTranslation('name', $locale);

        return app($class, $class_args)->{$method}(...[$string, ...$method_args]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and got error :


 Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object
 
 
 Also I see using of app( only in the second file. Could you please check content of config/tags.php inyour answer ?
 
 $ php -v
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jan 24 2022 10:42:33) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 8.83.2

Comment: It worked on my end. Maybe your config values are cached. Run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I moved next but got error :

 General error: 1364 Field 'slug' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `vt2_tags` (`name`, `type`, `order_column`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ({"en":"Hamlet"}, votesTagType, 1, 2022-03-01, 2022-03-01))
 
I suppose it is raised by line in my seeder:
         $lNewVote->attachTag(SpatieTag::findOrCreate('Hamlet', $this->votes_tag_type));

Looks like some misconfigure with Spatie/Tags. Do you have this error on your side ?